# How to expose a value of component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've made a custom Dropdown component in React and would like to expose a method for getting current value. e.g. `function value(){return this.state.selected}` and then use refs to get that value. How can I do that?

PS. I know that the preferred way to communicate between components is thru props and I am already calling a 'change' function thru props. But I am hoping to be able to inspect and hopefully set component values, e.g. for testing and non-react integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the method just like any other method:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    value() {
       return this.state.selected;
    }

    render() {
       // ...
    }
}
```